# Where does SugarCRM/SuiteCRM set file permissions?

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

Where does sugarcrm (6.5) and it's fork suitecrm (7.x) set file permissions for files it creates?

I have seen config.php with the variable:

```
'default_permissions' => array (
    'dir_mode' => 1528,
    'file_mode' => 436,
    'user' => '',
    'group' => '',
),
```

but that does not seem to be the same permissions that are assigned to cache files. See files in:

```
cache/smarty/templates_c
```

which have `644` permissions rather than `660`. This means that I have to manual `chmod` the files if I want to edit them.

So my question: where are file permissions set in sugarcrm/suitecrm?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After wrestling with this for many moons, I finally tracked down two additional obscure places SugarCRM/SuiteCRM sets file permissions.

**utils.php**  around line 136:

```
'default_permissions' => array (
    'dir_mode' => 02770,
    'file_mode' => 0660,
    'chown' => '',
    'chgrp' => '',
),
```

and the kicker for me, **Smarty.class.php** around line 504:

```
/**
 * default file permissions
 *
 * @var integer
 */
var $_file_perms           = 0644;

/**
 * default dir permissions
 *
 * @var integer
 */
var $_dir_perms               = 0771;
```

Hopefully this helps someone else. I'll wait to accept an answer in case someone has more to add.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `config.php's`

`'file_mode' => 436,`
should actually be

`'file_mode' => 432,`

Try changing it and see if the files are now given `660`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

See if `/install/installSystemCheck.php` is what you are looking for, on my `v7.2.1` line `217`